# connect to windows server 2003 from redhat linux client through ssh

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003

I want to connect windows server 2003 remotely from red hat Linux client. I know that Linux has SSH but windows doesn't have. So is there any way.

Comment: What would you like to do, once you are connected?  Do you want a remote desktop, by chance?  There are utilities for that, like `rdesktop`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RDP with either tsclient  (Terminal Server client) or rdesktop.
Enable Remote Desktop on your windows server and open up TCP port 3389.

Alternatively, install a free VNC server software such as UltraVNC on windows server.
Open TCP port 5900.
Use vncviewer from your linux client.

You can also enable Telnet service on windows server 2003.

There is also a free SSH daemon for windows at 
http://www.freesshd.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin has OpenSSH and you can set it up on Windows Server 2003,2008,2012 just fine.

http://www.cygwin.com/

I've used it to provide ssh connectivity to our windows servers for code deployments, etc.

A quick search should provide several how-to's on configuring it, but basically just install Cygwin and during setup, Select OpenSSH under +Net and select cygrunsrv under +Admin as well in order to run OpenSSH as a Windows service.

Start a cygwin bash shell as an Administrator

Run `ssh-host-config`, answer yes to all questions, and when prompted to "Enter the value of CYGWIN for the daemon", enter '**ntsec**', which enables communication with the NT authentication database.  Now start the new service in Windows services.